# Bulk/ Batch insert in Mongo takes time 15 sec to 10000 documents

Tags: php, mongodb, configuration, bulkinsert, jenssegers-mongodb

Bulk insert in Mongo takes time i.e average 15 seconds to insert 10000 documents in a collection.

My System is 8 core and 16 GB RAM.

How can I reduce response time for Mongo Insertion? What mongo configurations can be done to reduce execution time?

```
db.getCollection('temp').insert([{id:1},{id:10000}])
```

Each document contain 25-30 properties. I am using [jenssegers](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) library.

Comment: have you tried  bulk-insert: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/#bulk-insert

Comment: I am familiar with java driver and client level, no idea how to do it using jenssegers-mongodb.